# write the inverse of: $y= 3(4)^{2x+1} + 1$

Tags: exponential-function, inverse

write the inverse of:   $y= 3(4)^{2x+1} + 1$

This is what I did:

$
\begin{align}
x=& 3(4)^{2y+1} + 1\\
x-1=& 3(4)^{2y+1} \\
\frac {(x-1)} 3=& (4)^{2y+1}\\
\log((x-1)/3)=& (2y+1)\log(4)\\
\log((x-1)/3)=& 2y\log(4)+\log(4)\\
y=&[\log((x-1)/3)-\log(4)]/2\log(4)
\end{align}
$

Did I do this correctly?

Comment: At some point the $y$ became $x$ and then back again to $y$, but yes, the rest is fine. To complete the problem you can compute the domain of the inverse.

Comment: Also it should be $\dots /(2\log(4))$, not $\dots/2\log(4)$. See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a mathjax guide for correct typesetting.

Comment: Would it kill you to put your code between \$ signs?

Comment: Yes, the computation seems correct.